# Swap the elements of two sequences, such that the difference of the element-sums gets minimal.

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, data-structures

An interview question:

> Given two non-ordered integer sequences `a` and `b`, their size is n, all
>   numbers are randomly chosen: Exchange the elements of `a` and `b`, such that the sum of the elements of `a` minus the sum of the elements of `b` is minimal.

Given the example:

```
a = [ 5 1 3 ]
b = [ 2 4 9 ]
```

The result is (1 + 2 + 3) - (4 + 5 + 9) = -12.

My algorithm: Sort them together and then put the first smallest `n` ints in `a` and left in `b`. It is O(n lg n) in time and O(n) in space. I do not know how to improve it to an algorithm with O(n) in time and O(1) in space. O(1) means that we do not need more extra space except seq 1 and 2 themselves.

Any ideas ?

An alternative question would be: What if we need to minimize the absolute value of the differences (minimize `|sum(a) - sum(b)|`)?

A python or C++ thinking is preferred.

Comment: Sounds like a homework. If so, please tag accordingly.

Comment: It can't be O(1) in space if you consider the original a and b lists. If you don't consider them, then simply swap the values directly. In either case, please provide more details in the question.

Comment: @GaretJax, How to swap efficiently with O(n) time ?

Comment: Simply use a single temporary variable for a single element (O(1) space) and iterate over the list (O(n) time)).

Comment: -1 "exchange elements of a and b" is extremely vague -- I detect about 2.01 understandings of this in the answers.

Comment: @GaretJax, would you please show (with details) that how to use only one variable to do the swap so that the final result is optimal ?  thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Revised solution:

1. Merge both lists x = merge(a,b).
2. Calculate median of x (complexity O(n) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm )
3. Using this median swap elements between a and b. That is, find an element in a that is less than median, find one in b that is more than median and swap them

Final complexity: O(n)

Minimizing absolute difference is NP complete since it is equivalent to the knapsack problem.

Comment: Could you explain the equivalence?  It seems clear to me that the OP's solution of sorting and putting the smallest values in a will minimize sum(a)-sum(b): what am I missing?

Comment: Are you talking about the second part (minimizing the absolute value) or both? Because I don't think it applies to the first one, to obtain the highest negative difference place the n/2 lowest numbers in one list and the n/2 highest in the other, as the OP said.

Comment: @DSM I thought you were calculating absolute minimum. If is is just minimum use the new solution. No sorting required :)

Comment: @GaretJax My bad. See the new solution.

Comment: Great O(n) time solution. It can be adapted to be O(1) in memory too!

Comment: Good link, BTW: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm

Comment: For the median you have to sort x! If you sort x, complexity is not O(n).

Comment: For an optimal solution we can't get better than O(n log n/2) it seems to me: We have to find the N/2 smallest values in A and B which I'm pretty sure is impossible in O(N).

Comment: @ChristianAmmer It is possible to find median in O(n). See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: @ElKamina: Thanks for the link, I didn't know that and I think that's not obvious at first sight – but you have edited your answer, that's good for people like me not knowing that :-) therefore +1.

Answer (score 2):

What comes into my mind is following algorithm outline:

1. C = A v B
2. Partitially sort #A (number of A) Elements of C
3. Subtract the sum of the last #B Elements from C from the sum of the first #A Elements from C.

You should notice, that you **don't need to sort all elements**, it is enough to find the number of A smallest elements. Your example given:

1. C = {5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 9}
2. C = {1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 9}
3. (1 + 2 + 3) - (5 + 4 + 9) = -12

A C++ solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // Initialize 'a' and 'b'
    int ai[] = { 5, 1, 3 };
    int bi[] = { 2, 4, 9 };
    std::vector<int> a(ai, ai + 3);
    std::vector<int> b(bi, bi + 3);

    // 'c' = 'a' merged with 'b'
    std::vector<int> c;
    c.insert(c.end(), a.begin(), a.end());
    c.insert(c.end(), b.begin(), b.end());

    // partitially sort #a elements of 'c'
    std::partial_sort(c.begin(), c.begin() + a.size(), c.end());

    // build the difference
    int result = 0;
    for (auto cit = c.begin(); cit != c.end(); ++cit)
        result += (cit < c.begin() + a.size()) ? (*cit) : -(*cit);

    // print result (and it's -12)
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's not O(N) though, but O(N log N/2) if we want the optimal solution (ie the N/2 smallest values).

Comment: @Voo: You are right, but does an O(N) algorithm exist – I can't think of any? And I think the median solution is also not O(N), for getting the median, the sequence has to be sorted, otherwise you are picking a random element from the middle (or am I wrong)?

Comment: Oh I agree that O(N log N/2) seems to be the best possible solution. After all we need the N/2 smallest values and I really don't see how that'd be possible in O(N).